# GCC won't use self-built libcurl?

Tags: c++, linux, curl, build

I'm trying to build libcurl to link latest version statically to my program. Output folder contains the build files.

However when I build and run this code:

```cpp
// g++ gontest.cpp -o gontest -Ilibs/curl/gonout/include/curl -Llibs/curl/gonout/lib -lcurl
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto data = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW);
  std::cout << "curlversion: " << data->version << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

...I'm getting the system version of curl library (7.6.8), not the built one (8.8.0).

It's the same output as if I'd built it with this:

```
g++ gontest.cpp -o gontest -lcurl
```

I've tried several versions of the command, including:

```
# none works
~$ g++ gontest.cpp -o gontest -Ilibs/curl/gonout/include/curl -Llibs/curl/gonout/lib -l:libs/curl/gonout/lib/libcurl.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:libs/curl/gonout/lib/libcurl.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

~$ g++ gontest.cpp -o gontest -Ilibs/curl/gonout/include/curl -Llibs/curl/gonout/lib -l:/libs/curl/gonout/lib/libcurl.a
~$ g++ gontest.cpp -o gontest -Ilibs/curl/gonout/include/curl -Llibs/curl/gonout/lib -l:./libs/curl/gonout/lib/libcurl.a
~$ g++ gontest.cpp -o gontest -Ilibs/curl/gonout/include/curl -Llibs/curl/gonout/lib -l:./libs/curl/gonout/lib/libcurl.so
~$ g++ gontest.cpp -o gontest -Ilibs/curl/gonout/include/curl -Llibs/curl/gonout/lib -l:/libs/curl/gonout/lib/libcurl.so
~$ g++ gontest.cpp -o gontest -Ilibs/curl/gonout/include/curl -Llibs/curl/gonout/lib -l:libs/curl/gonout/lib/libcurl.so
# note that it exists
~$ ls ./libs/curl/gonout/lib/libcurl.a
./libs/curl/gonout/lib/libcurl.a
```

Why is my custom-built library getting ignored?

Comment: What does the `:` after `-l` do? I've never used that when I link and I can't find it in [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/gcc-command-options/options-for-linking.html#cmdoption-llibrary)

Comment: Are you trying to link with a static or a shared library?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've seen it somewhere as an option to link to a concrete file, instead of letting it search for it. Primarily, I don't get why this doesn't work as I expect it to do (my understanding is limited, but still)
`g++ gontest.cpp -o gontest -Ilibs/curl/gonout/include/curl -Llibs/curl/gonout/lib -lcurl`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't really have a preference at the moment. However, I don't know how to specify one or the other (both `libcurl.a` and `libcurl.so` are in the directory).

Comment: Ld links with shared libraries by default, use `-static` to link with the .a

Comment: _"I've seen it somewhere..."_ - but were they using `g++`? `g++` doesn't seem to support `-l:` and as @SamVarshavchik mentioned (and the documentation also states)  _"If both static and shared libraries are found, the linker gives preference to linking with the shared library unless the `-static` option is used."_

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, might've been gcc, might be someone lying. Anyways, that's just what I've tried on top of what I'd expect to work.

Comment: It's better to read the documentation. The chapter on `-l` isn't that long.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yeah, that at least does something (doesn't build, because I'd have to link everything else with it). Errors start with `libs/curl/gonout/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-netrc.o): in function Curl_parsenetrc':
netrc.c:(.text+0x70c): warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking`
So it at least appears to use proper libcurl.
Can I somehow use "libcurl.so" without using the system-wide one?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Fair point, however, reading it now, I only see order of inputs, but no way (or info in general) how to specify which `*.so` library will be used. My current issue (If I'm not mistaken - and I might be) is that g++ ignores my -L path and simply goes for the system wide location and I don't know how to prevent that.

Is there a way to "force" g++ to use that particular build? 

Is there a reason as to why it might not be picked if my first g++ command is correct?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The argument to `-l` is passed on to the linker (which is indepedent of gcc/g++). The interpretation is up to the linker. The binutils linker at least supports `:` in order to specify full file name (instead of implicitly adding prefix and suffix). But I don't know whether it supports full relative paths (@OP: try putting the path in `-L` and only the filename to `-l:`). See e.g. https://manpages.debian.org/testing/binutils-common/ld.1.en.html#l.

Comment: You can also add a full library path directly as argument to `gcc`/`g++` btw. if you don't want any search to happen.

Comment: @user17732522 Oh, cool! Perhaps  _**I**_ should read the doc properly :-)

Comment: So, I've built an incredibly simple example library to test all of it and the result basically is that ".so" library won't be used, unless it's installed in system wide folder. See the difference here: https://imgur.com/a/jkKPFHd  O_O I've named one lib as curl and other differently and the outputs (last two lines) are different, because knihovna isn't visible at all, whereas curl is found as a system version and simply doesn't have my test function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building .so, it either needs to be linked to the executable by modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or, it needs to be built with a custom include path defined with flags `-Wl,-rpath,<path to lib directory>`

[image: code]

In this example we are using `-Wl,-rpath,.` where `.` adds the current directory to the list of usable library locations.

Please note that this way isn't a standard/proper way on Linux and normally, I'd simply upgrade curl on a given machine. It just isn't an option right now. Please, don't use it unless you have to.